# Can I configure the Orchard Media Library Picker Field to require an image with specific dimensions?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

In the past I've used the [Image Field Module](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.ImageField) to require a user to provide an image of specific dimensions and it's worked great. I like the new Media Library Picker Field and it's integration with the Image Editor module to allow for cropping and re-sizing.

What I'd like to do is use the Media Library Picker Field but require the user to crop and/or re-size the image to specific dimensions. Is there any way to configure it that way? So far, the best I've come up with is to provide some help text to the user suggesting that they re-size the image to desired dimensions.

Should I just stick with the Image Field if I must have the image meet specific dimensions or is there a better way with the Media Library Picker Field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't enforce that the image is supplied with specific dimensions using the Orchard 1.7+ media processing features, however you can ensure that it is *displayed* with correct dimensions.

Orchard 1.7 introduces the concept of media profiles, which effectively allow you to create a bunch of image transformations, name them, and then use them arbitrarily throughout your site.

On a recent project I was given a load of customer profile pictures for a testimonial page on an Orchard site. They were supplied in a variety of different sizes, and I knew I needed at least 2 different sizes (one for the main testimonial page, and a smaller one for testimonial widgets shown on other pages).

In the Admin Dashboard, I went to Media -> Profiles and created a new Media Profile called Customer_Profile_Regular, then added a Resize filter to scale it down to 100x100px (the resize filter is quite flexible, and you can create your own filters easily by implementing the `IImageFilterProvider` interface).

I did the same for a second profile, Customer_Profile_Small, scaling down to 50x50.

Then, using Shape Tracing, I overrode the existing Media Library Picker field display shape, and replaced it with this:

```
@{
   var imagesField = Model.ContentItem.Testimonial.CustomerProfile;
}
@if(imagesField.MediaParts.Any()) {
    <div class="customer-profile-image">
        @Display.MediaUrl(Profile: "Customer_Profile_Regular", Path: imagesField.MediaParts.First().MediaUrl)
    </div>
}
```

For the testimonial widget, it was simply a case of creating a similar shape override, supplying the other profile name.

Now I can upload any image to my media library, and use it as a customer profile image on a testimonial. Orchard will automatically resize (or perform other operations on) the image based on the profile I tell it to use, the result of which is stored in the site's Media folder so that it is only regenerated when necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I was playing around with media profiles yesterday and leaning in the same direction. I think I'll combine that with help text that let's the user know to re-size the image manually if they don't want the filter to do it for them.